# Http request incomplete

Tags: java, http

I am trying to make an HTTP request for a personal project and for some reason my request did not return the full HTML.

I don't know if I'm forgetting anything, I tried googling it but I can't find anything that helped.

```
URL link = new Url("https:\\www (...)");

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)link.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

String inputLine = "";
while (in.readLine() != null){
    inputLine += in.readLine();
}

in.close();
con.disconnect();
```

I was expecting the full HTML page, but I got part of it, like:

HTML Page:

```
<div>
    <span>product</span>
    <span>price</span>
</div>
```

received:

```
<div>
    <span>product</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're throwing way every odd line by calling `readLine()` twice in the loop. Rearrange.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what this does:

```java
String inputLine = "";
while (in.readLine() != null){
    inputLine += in.readLine();
}
```

You're checking if a line does not equal null, then appending the *next* line to the string. This means you skip every other line.

To fix this, you can assign a temporary variable the value of the `nextLine()` call and use that instead:

```java
String inputLine = "";
String line = in.readLine();
while (line != null){
    inputLine += line;
    line = in.readLine();
}
```

Inline:

```java
String inputLine = "";
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    inputLine += line;
}
```

Comment: it works, another mistake for inattention, thanks

Comment: Note that `for(;;) { String line = in.readLine(); if(line == nul) break; inputLine += line; }` would be cleaner. Case 1. you avoid duplicating the `line = in.readLine()` and Case 2. you avoid an assignment inside a condition.